# Javascript - transpose dict into array

Tags: javascript

I have a the following dict I would like to transpose:

```
dict = {
         'column1': [1, 2, 3],
         'column2': [4, 5, 6],
         'column3': [7, 8, 9]
        }
```

Into:

```
transposed_array = [
                    [1, 4, 7],
                    [2, 5, 8],
                    [3, 6, 9]
                  ]
```

Comment: Objects don't have a strict order, do you expect them to sort alphabetically?

Comment: And what part of this have you had trouble doing? This is a requirement, but you're missing an actual question.

Comment: @Nit Not alphabetically, I guess (think about column9 and column10)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution (updated for non square matrices):

```
var dict = {
     'column1': [1, 2, 3],
     'column2': [4, 5, 6],
     'column3': [7, 8, 9]
}
var keys = Object.keys(dict);
var transposedMatrix = dict[keys[0]].map(function(col,i){  
  return keys.map(function(_,j){ return dict[keys[j]][i] })
});
```

[Demonstration](http://jsbin.com/revawesaku/2/watch?js,console,output)

Note that this code assumes that objects *do* have ordered keys, which has always been the case in all known ES implementations and [is now normalized by ES6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30076219/does-es6-introduce-a-well-defined-order-of-enumeration-for-object-properties).

Comment: This answer seems fine. Interested in the reason for downvoting

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan [Why don't you just test](http://jsbin.com/ridonurivu/2/watch?js,console,output) ? ;)

Comment: @RGraham Object properties order **is** now guaranteed, and the spec follows what the browsers were already doing.

Comment: your solution does'nt work if the dict is different: ex `var dict = { 'column1': [1],'column2': [4], 'column3': [7]}`

Comment: @BelowtheRadar I've edited with a version working with non square matrixes.

Answer (score 1):

```
var dict = {
         'column1': [1, 2, 3],
         'column2': [4, 5, 6],
         'column3': [7, 8, 9]
        };
var transposed_array =[];
for (key in dict){
    transposed_array.push(dict[key]);

}
console.log(transposed_array);
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/o6hwj0p6/)
**Updated:**

```
var dict = {
         'column1': [1, 2, 3],
         'column2': [4, 5, 6],
         'column3': [7, 8, 9]
        };
var transposed_array =[];
for (key in dict){
    transposed_array.push(dict[key]);

}
function transposeArray(array){

    var newArray = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
        newArray.push([]);
    }

    for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
        for(var j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++){
            newArray[j].push(array[i][j]);
        }
    }

    return newArray;
}
console.log(transposeArray(transposed_array));
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/o6hwj0p6/1/)

Comment: data is not transposed

Comment: what does it mean `data is not transposed`??

Answer (score 1):

basically first find the shared part of the keys, then the endings, after sort reassamle the array. the result is numerical orderd if number otherwise the order is maintained.

```
var dict = {
        'column3': [7, 8, 9],
        'column2': [4, 5, 6],
        'column1': [1, 2, 3]
    },
    keys = Object.keys(dict),
    samePart = keys.reduce(function (a, b) {
        var i = 0, l = Math.min(a.length, b.length);
        while (i < l && a[i] === b[i]) { i++; }
        return a.substr(0, i);
    }),
    otherPart = keys.map(function (e) { return e.slice(samePart.length); }).sort(function (a, b) { return a - b; }),
    transposedMatrix = [].map.call(otherPart, function (col, i) { return dict[samePart + col].map(function (_, j) { return dict[samePart + col][j]; }); });
```